# Failed to spawn ngrokrequest to http://127.0.0.1:4041/api/tunnels failed, reason: read ECONNRESET

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot

I have a problem with my Bot Framework Emulator.

`Failed to spawn ngrok request to http://127.0.0.1:4041/api/tunnels failed, reason: read Econnreset`

I have to use ngrok for my Bot because I need to bypass the firewall to get some answers from my Bot because I use my Bot on Azure.
I have all done my ngrok is running on port 4040 and my Bot Framework takes the port 4041 why isn't he taking the 4040? Because 4041 doesn't exist.

[image: This is how it looks you can see on the right side the errors]

I would be very happy if I can get a solution to my problem.

I wish you all a good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because NGROK was already running. NGROK is already running with a webhost on port 4040. I *think* the emulator is trying to use the next port up (4041), but then failing to launch ngrok because it's already running.

If your goal is only to debug locally for bot running on Azure, then de-select the following  setting in the Emulator.

> Run ngrok when the Emulator starts up

Restart Emulator and use the localhost address to debug.

Comment: Thanks a lot now it works i have restarted my computer you're right!